# CSS: Calculate the overflow of two overlapping rectangles after one has been rotated

Tags: html, css, sass, css-transforms, css-calc

kind of an odd question I know, but I wanted to know if it's possible to calculate the width a rectangle needs to be to perfectly fit into another rectangle after the first one has been rotate with `transform: rotate`. Here's a picture of what I'm trying to say:

[image: Example of what I'm trying to achieve]

Ideally I want this do be dynamic, so it doesn't depend on the actual with of the first rectangle.

I'm using SCSS and this is what I got so far:

```
.background-box {
  background: black;
  padding: rem(30px 40px);
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  &:after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    @include transform(rotate(5deg));
    border: rem(2px) solid $primary;
    background: transparent;
    z-index: -1;
  }
}
```

HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="background-box">
    //CONTENT
</div>
```

Now I want the `width` of rectangle 2 (the one built by `:after`) to be *X* to fit inside the parent element. Something like `width: calc(100% - overflow)`.

Is this possible or do I need to work around with something like `width: 98%`?

Comment: It's very unclear what you want to do. If they have the same widh-height, they will ' fit ' . Please explain more what you want to achieve

Comment: Okay so I've got to rectangles. Rectangle 1 has a sertain `width` based on it's content. I've created a second rectangle (Rectangle 2) with `:after` in CSS. The width of this recangle is 100% in the Given example. Now I want the width of rectangle 2 to be something like `width: calc(100% - overlapping space of the rectangle);`.

Comment: Well you said in your question `Now I want the width of rectangle 2 (the one built by :after) to still be 100% of the parent width.` :) That;s what's confusing.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I've edited this part of the question. :)

Comment: well that overflow i think it's too dynamic to calculate with CSS. What you can do is make a 'safe' assumption and  make something like : https://jsfiddle.net/bcqw0y58/3/ It depends very much of the rotation. How many deg.

Comment: I don’t think this is necessarily “too dynamic”, what this basically needs is proper application of some trigonometric functions … and then probably something like this, https://gist.github.com/kamikat/c4d472ce3c61feec6376 (“SCSS/SASS module calculating sin/cos/tan using Taylor Expansion.”)

Comment: Yeah I've thought about that too. Would probably work for me as well but I thought maybe there is a dynamic way of achieving this.

Comment: @04FS Yikes. I wouldn't even be able to calculate my Issue on paper :D Maybe I should have listend in school a little bit more..

Comment: On second thought, I’m not too sure this would work without “fixed” element dimensions (and in that regard, calling it “too dynamic” probably makes sense.) Theoretically, I’d start with taking the point in the middle of rect 1 as “origin”, and half of the length of the diagonal of the rectangle as radius. Then you’d need to calculate the angle of the line from the middle to, say, the upper right corner first (that would need knowing width and height though, or at least the aspect ratio.) […]

Comment: […] Adding your rotation to that angle, you could get the position of that corner of the rotated rect 2, and then the distance of that from the middle point on the X axis, by applying some of the basic “triangle math” good ol’ Pythagoras taught us …

Comment: @04FS Okay, I'll try that. Thank you for your effort and the hints.

Comment: I’d probably give that a go in JavaScript first though, that might be easier to debug, plus you can read the actual element dimensions, and you have trigonometric functions available via the Math object without having to add any additional components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an illustration to better show the issue and the calculation we need to do:

```css
.box {
  margin: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  outline: 2px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.rect {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 49%, red 49%, red 52%, transparent 52%);
  animation: change 5s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes change {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(53deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="rect">
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, we have the diagonal line (the red one) that we need to decrease in order to avoid the overflow.

[image]

In the below figure we have our rotation angle (in blue) and the angle in purple that is based on the dimension of the rectangle. From this we have the following formula:

```
cos(PurpleAngle) = width/X
cos(PurpleAngle - BlueAngle) = width/X1
```

where `X1` is the width needed for our diagonal (delimited by the yellow cross) and `X` is the width of the diagonal (the full red line).

We can then write this:

```
X/X1 = cos(PurpleAngle - BlueAngle)/cos(PurpleAngle)
```

then

```
X/X1 = (cos(PurpleAngle)*cos(BlueAngle) + sin(PurpleAngle)*sin(BlueAngle))/cos(PurpleAngle)
```

We simplify to

```
X/X1 = cos(BlueAngle) + tan(PurpleAngle)*sin(BlueAngle)
```

We know the `BlueAngle` which is our rotation angle and we can easily find `tan(PurpleAngle)` which is simply `Height/Width`. Yes, we need to know the width and heigth or at least the ratio between both. In my case I used a `0.5` ratio so will have:

```
X/X1 = cos(BlueAngle) + 0.5*sin(BlueAngle)
```

Now we can see this as another rotation in the Y axis where we will have `cos(B) = X1/X`.

Example:

```css
.box {
  margin: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  outline: 2px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.rect {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform:rotate(20deg) rotateY(25.84deg);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 49%, red 49%, red 52%, transparent 52%);
  animation: change 5s linear infinite alternate;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="rect">
  </div>
</div>
```

Or we can also see it as a scale transform with a factor equal to `X1/X`:

Example:

```css
.box {
  margin: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  outline: 2px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.rect {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform:rotate(20deg) scale(0.9);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 49%, red 49%, red 52%, transparent 52%);
  animation: change 5s linear infinite alternate;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="rect">
  </div>
</div>
```

So all you want to do is to know the ratio, and the rotation angle then use the fomula to find the scale value or rotation value.

More examples:

```css
.box {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 75px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  outline: 2px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.rect {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!-- 1/(cos(20deg) + 0.5*sin(20deg)) -->
<div class="box">
  <div class="rect" style="
  transform:rotate(20deg) scale(0.9);">
  </div>
</div>
<!-- 1/(cos(45deg) + 1*sin(45deg)) -->
<div class="box" style="height:150px">
  <div class="rect" style="
  transform:rotate(45deg) scale(0.707);">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- 1/(cos(5deg) + 0.333*sin(5deg)) -->
<div class="box" style="height:50px">
  <div class="rect" style="
  transform:rotate(5deg) scale(0.972);">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- 1/(cos(15deg) + 2*sin(15deg)) -->
<div class="box" style="height:300px;">
  <div class="rect" style="
  transform:rotate(15deg) scale(0.674);">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Using SASS you can consider this link (https://unindented.org/articles/trigonometry-in-sass/) where you can find the definition of `cos()` `sin()` then you simply do:

```
@function scale-factor($angle, $ratio) {
  @return 1/(cos($angle) + $ratio*sin($angle)); 
}


div {
  transform:rotate(15deg) scale(scale-factor(15deg,2));
}
```

And you will get this:

```
div {
  transform: rotate(15deg) scale(0.6740525224);
}
```

---

For the CSS solution, we can also rely on `calc()` to make the calculation easier by doing `scale(calc(1 / (cos(a) + r*sin(a)))` where we only need to calculate `cos()` and `sin()`

Comment: this is what i call a quality answer